# disable button when first click in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to disable button when user first click it so it must not save multiple record if a user have a slow connection. Im using asp.net mvc2

Comment: for jquery look at unbind(), might work - http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Of course you have to adjust the selector.

Comment: It does not work for me. This code prevent button click at all, so that form is not submitted once as it should.

Comment: Put this just before disabling button if you want your form been submitted `$("form").submit();`

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery's [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/). With this, the event handler is executed only once. Inside the event handler you can disable or change the style.

Example from jQuery site:

```
$('#foo').one('click', function() {
  alert('This will be displayed only once.');
});
```