# User double click submit create 2 post

Tags: php, jquery

I have a web application can let user create post and write into DB

However I have a problem when user double click submit button, it create 2 posts. The file become query twice, is any way to solve this problem. (I use jquery Post to next file and write into DB)

```
$.post('add.php',{title:post.title.value,...}
```

Comment: I just click 3 times, it create 3 post

Comment: thats mean... if you clicked 4 times so you will get 4 posts !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your click or submit handler you can disable the button like this:

```
$('#add_button').click(function() {
  $(this).attr('disabled', true);
  // Do your post stuff
  $.post('add.php', {}, function(data) {
    // Enable the button after the post, or on your success function
    $(this).attr('disabled', false);
  });

})
```

EDIT: As @roasted stated, you can also use `.prop`, instead of `.attr` on your JQuery object.

Comment: use .prop() and its perfect

Comment: I try this, but if i click very fast(many times) it will still post twice

Comment: Try using a `$.ajax` function with `success` and `error` callbacks, and inside these callbacks you enable the button again. Here are the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
   $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573849/disable-button-when-first-click-in-jquery)

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You disable the button after the first click using javascript. That way you will not have any double posts.